# NodeJS connecting to sql server using node-mssql does not work

Tags: sql-server, node.js, node-mssql

I use a named instance of SQL Server Express 2012
If I try to connect to it using SSMS it works, using these parameters:

```
Server name: mit-007\SQLEXPRESS2012
Authentication: SQL Server Authentication
    Login: sa
    Password: mit
```

Using node-mssql:

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'mit',
    server: 'mit-007',
    driver: 'tedious',
    database: 'Delvi',
    options: {
        instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS2012'
    }
};

sql.connect(config).then(function(){ // and so on
```

It logs this error

```
{ [ConnectionError: Failed to connect to mit-007:undefined in 15000ms]
  name: 'ConnectionError',
  message: 'Failed to connect to mit-007:undefined in 15000ms',
  code: 'ETIMEOUT' }
```

Answer (score 6):

After browsing around I solved the problem, here's what I did

1. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. Click SQL Server Network Configuration => Protocols for SQLEXPRESS2012
3. Double click TCP/IP
4. Change Enabled to Yes
5. Click IP Addresses
6. IPAll => Clear TCP Dynamic Ports, set TCP Port 1433
7. Open services.msc
8. Start SQL Server Browser Service
9. Restart SQL Server

I'm not sure that every single one of the steps above are necessary, but they worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I think `mit-007` is not your network adress.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms189921(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: It's the server's hostname, and it works if I use PHP to connect, just not from nodejs

Comment: Try to define also port then. Default it 1433.

Comment: https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql/issues/155 - similar problem, maybe it helps.

Comment: Thank you, that link eventually helped me solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a flaw in the tedious driver logic that indicates that the port is "undefined" when running on a mac platform.

The program (testtedious.js) runs fine when using the following configuration settings on a MS Windows platform:

```
var connectionConfig = {
    userName: 'xxx',
    password: 'yyy',
    database: 'zzz',
    server: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 1443,
    debug: true,
    driver: 'tedious',
    options: {
        encrypt: false,
        instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS',
        database: 'www',
        useColumnNames: false,
        debug: {
            packet: true,
            data: true,
            payload: true,
            token: true,
            log: true
        }
    }
};
```

However, when running on a mac I get the following error:

```
$ node testtedious.js
Tedious-Connection-Pool: filling pool with 2
Tedious-Connection-Pool: creating connection: 1
Tedious-Connection-Pool: creating connection: 2
Tedious-Connection-Pool: connection connected: 1
Tedious-Connection-Pool: connection closing because of error
{ ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:undefined in 15000ms
    at ConnectionError (/project-dir/node_modules/tedious/lib/errors.js:12:12)
    at Connection.connectTimeout (/project-dir/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:467:28)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
  message: 'Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:undefined in 15000ms',
  code: 'ETIMEOUT' }
Tedious-Connection-Pool: connection connected: 2
Tedious-Connection-Pool: connection closing because of error
{ ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:undefined in 15000ms
    at ConnectionError (/project-dir/node_modules/tedious/lib/errors.js:12:12)
    at Connection.connectTimeout (/project-dir/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:467:28)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
  message: 'Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:undefined in 15000ms',
  code: 'ETIMEOUT' }
Tedious-Connection-Pool: creating connection: 3
Tedious-Connection-Pool: creating connection: 4
```

Here's the "fix":

```
var connectionConfig = {
    userName: 'xxx',
    password: 'yyy',
    database: 'zzz',
    server: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 1443,
    debug: true,
    driver: 'tedious',
    options: {
        port: 1443,
        encrypt: false,
        database: 'www',
        useColumnNames: false,
        debug: {
            packet: true,
            data: true,
            payload: true,
            token: true,
            log: true
        }
    }
};
```

Note the movement of the `port` setting into options and the removal of the `instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS'` option setting.